# Table creation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these three tables which references each other with foreign key.

```
create table category(cat_id int primary key auto_increment, cat_name varchar(30),cat_label varchar(30));

create table product(prod_id int primary key auto_increment, cat_id int(11), prod_name varchar(100),prod_desc varchar(100), foreign key (cat_id) references category(cat_id))

create table sales(sales_id int primary key auto_increment, prod_id int(11), sales_name varchar(100),sales_desc varchar(100),
foreign key(prod_id) references product(prod_id));
```

As am new to Rails, I know how to create just a table using scaffold as per below.

```
rails generate scaffold category cat_id:integer cat_name:string cat_label:string
```

How do I create the above three tables in Rails?

Comment: @jvillian I do not understand what you mean. the scafold above can only generate table for category. how do I go about with product table and sales table which has foreign key references. Do I have to create the table one by one

Comment: Why do you need `cat_id` instead of `id`?

Comment: This is a very basic question. As stated in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), we expect you to do some basic research. Generating a model is covered in a great many books, web articles, and is easily [googleable](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+generate+model).  If you've already done `rails g model` (which is unclear), then you'll need to run your migrations - which is [goobleable](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+migrate) and is discussed in the [Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org./active_record_migrations.html#running-migrations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from terminal

```
rails g model category name
rails g model product name category:references
rails g model sale name product:references
```

It will generate 3 migrations with 3 tables and references each other with foreign keys.

Also you can manually write all you need in one migration.

Comment: Thanks alot sir Mechnicov. It seems that all the table to be referenced for  must have id at primary key. cat_id  does not work but id works. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you can start by writing in your console these lines:

```
rails g model Category cat_id:integer cat_name:string car_label:string

rails g model Product prod_id:integer cat_id:integer prod_name:string prod_desc:string
```

this will generate your two tables (you should try to create table Sales yourself), you could go through this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-model, it basically covers all you need.

Then to set up your foreign keys, you should go through associations, which you can find as well here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

You should read it carefully because the Rails convent has a lot of unique stuff other programming languages don't have.

Comment: Thank You so much. Your answer is also useful to me. so I upvotes